# bigConmmerce-Stencil push

Tags: bigcommerce-stencil-cli

stencil push
not ok -- Error: Request failed with status code 403

I checked token, and so did Url, but there will still be this error.

Change the token and check the url address. I hope there are other ideas to solve this problem.